# Can I use Markov's inequality in this exercise?

Tags: probability-theory

I am looking at Exercise 86 of Doukhan's *Stochastic models for time series*, which asks:

> If $E[X^2] < \infty$ prove that there exists a function $H:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ s.t. $\lim_{x\to\infty}\tfrac{H(x)}{x^2} = \infty$ and $E[H(|X|)]<\infty$.

It is suggested to find an increasing sequence $M_k$ such that $E[X^2\cdot 1_{X^2\ge M_k}] < \tfrac{1}{k^2}$.

1. The existence of such a sequence is not hard to prove. Indeed
   $$E[X^2] = \sum_{n\ge0}E[X^2\cdot 1_{X^2\in[n, n+1)}]$$
   and existence follows from the fact that this series converges. **Is there a way to give more explicit $M_k$ that work using the Markov inequality (which is presented just before this problem in the book)?**
2. Just to conclude: one then defines $H(x)=x^2\sum_{k\ge0}k1_{x\in[M_k, M_{k+1})}$ (with $M_0=0$). The fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\tfrac{H(x)}{x^2} = \infty$ is clear. For the other condition we have
   \begin{align}
   E[H(|X|)] ={}&E\left[X^2\sum_{k\ge0}k1_{|X|\in[M_k, M_{k+1})}\right]\\
   ={}&\sum_{k\ge0}kE\left[X^21_{|X|\in[M_k, M_{k+1})}\right]\\
   ={}&\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{k\ge n}E\left[X^21_{|X|\in[M_k, M_{k+1})}\right]\\
   ={}&\sum_{n\ge0}E\left[X^21_{|X|\ge M_k}\right]\\
   \le{}&\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1}{k^2}\\
   <{}&\infty\ .
   \end{align}

Comment: Markov's inequality does not heli in finding an $M_k$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you explain the idea/intuition behind your statement? Heuristics is fine :)

Comment: Markov's inequality gives an upper bound on the probability of $X$ being large; it is not useful for bounding expected values.